# HTML Canvas fails to drawImage

Tags: javascript, canvas

Given the following two objects:

```
function newDoodle() {
  var Doodle = {
    /* Variables for creating the canvases */
    cnvWdth: 800, 
    cnvHght: 250,
    bgCanvas: false,
    fgCanvas: false,
    bgContext: false,
    fgContext: false,
    bodyElement: false,

    /* Variables for future objects */
    background: false,

    init: function(bodyElement) {
      /* Set up the two canvas elements */
      this.bodyElement = bodyElement;
      this.bgCanvas = this.createCanvas('background');
      this.fgCanvas = this.createCanvas('foreground');
      this.bgContext = this.getContext(this.bgCanvas);
      this.fgContext = this.getContext(this.fgCanvas);

      /* Set up the background canvas */
      this.bgImage = newBackground();
      this.bgImage.init(this.bgContext);
    },

    createCanvas: function(id) {
      var canvas = $('<canvas />').appendTo(this.bodyElement);
      canvas.attr('width', this.cnvWdth);
      canvas.attr('height', this.cnvHght);

      return canvas[0];
    },

    getContext: function(canvas) {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      return context;
    }
  }
  return Doodle;
}

function newBackground() {
  var Background = {
    /* Background Image source variables */
    srcXPos: 0,
    srcYPos: 0,
    srcWdth: 800,
    srcHght: 250,

    bgImage: new Image(),
    bgImageSrc: 'doodle_background.png',
    context: false,

    init: function(ctx) {
      this.context = ctx;
      this.bgImage.addEventListener('load', this.drawBackground(), false);
      this.bgImage.src = this.bgImageSrc;
    },

    drawBackground: function() {
      this.context.drawImage(this.bgImage, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  return Background;
}
```

I store `newDoodle()`'s returned object into a variable and call its `init` function.  Ultimately it will call `newBackground()`'s object's `drawBackground()` function.  I've verified that both the image and contexts are valid, and even with `"use strict"`, nothing is reported in the console, yet nothing is getting drawn to the canvas.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
this.bgImage.addEventListener('load', this.drawBackground(), false);
```

See how you're *calling* `this.drawBackground` right here, and not *passing* it as an event handler?

What you probably want is this:

```
var that = this;
this.bgImage.addEventListener('load',
    function () { that.drawBackground(); }, false);
```

Note that you *cannot* shorten to

```
this.bgImage.addEventListener('load',
    this.drawBackground, false); // will not work!
```

since `drawBackground` needs the context  – the `this` context, not the canvas context. Well, that too. Anyway, I digress :)

Comment: Most appreciated!  Thank you very much!